# Find distinct pairs of a 2D array

Tags: c#, linq

I have this function to return distinct elements of an array:

```
public static object[] Distinct(object[] array)
{
     return array.Select(x => x.ToString()).Distinct().ToArray();
}
```

I would like to extend this to a matrix with 2 columns and it should return distinct pairs.

This obviously doesn't work:

```
public static object[,] Distinct(object[,] array)
{
    return array.Select((x,y) => x.ToString(), y.ToString()).Distinct().ToArray();
}
```

But I think it shows nicely what I'm trying to do. Any pointers would be great.

Comment: Why not return `string[]` and `string[,]` instead of `object[]` and `object[,]`?  That would make it clear that you're not returning the original objects passed in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could translate the 2D array into a sequence of `Tuple` and then run `Distinct` on that.  Then translate it back into a 2D array.

```
public static object[,] Distinct(object[,] array)
{
    var distinct = Enumerable.Range(0, array.GetLength(0))
        .Select(i => Tuple.Create(array[i, 0].ToString(), array[i, 1].ToString()))
        .Distinct()
        .ToList();
    var newArray = new object[distinct.Count, 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < distinct.Count; i++)
    {
        newArray[i, 0] = distinct[i].Item1;
        newArray[i, 1] = distinct[i].Item2;
    }

    return newArray;
}
```

Note that this is assuming that the length of the second dimension of the array is >= 2, and if it is greater then it's just return the values from the first 2 positions.

Answer (score 1):

Eventually you would do it as extension method with generic?

```
public static T[,] Distinct<T>(this T[,] array)
{
    var result = Enumerable.Range(0, array.GetLength(0))
        .Select(i => new { x = array[i, 0], y = array[i, 1] })
        .Distinct();

    T[,] ret = new T[result.Count(), 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < result.Count(); i++)
    {
        ret[i, 0] = result.ElementAt(i).x;
        ret[i, 1] = result.ElementAt(i).y;
    }

    return ret;
}
```

So this would be possible:

```
int[,] test = new int[,] { { 1, 2 }, { 1, 3 }, { 2, 4 }, { 1, 3 } };
var result = test.Distinct();
```

Comment: Better to use `ToList` for the result so you don't have to iterate the sequence for the call to `Count` and each call to `ElementAt`.

Comment: Might also want to consider a version that passes in a `IEqualityComparer<T>` that is passed to `Distinct` when you want to control how it compares the items in the array.